# Retrieve information from database in a variable

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables, google-api

I am trying to create a variable in my php code where I can use a value from my database to use user information. Basically, I'm trying to fetch the UserID from the database *desikitchen* where it matches the variable $dkuser.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
  $sqlStremail = "SELECT UserID
                FROM User 
                WHERE Name = '$dkuser'";

  $result = mysql_query($sqlStremail);

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

  $variable = $row["UserID"];

  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO desikitchen.Inventory (ItemName, ItemUser)
  VALUES ('{$itemname1}', '{$sqlStremail}')";
  $result = mysql_query($sql2);
```

Comment: Use dots to concat strings and variables. $sqlStremail = "SELECT UserID FROM User WHERE Name = '" . $dkuser . "'";  But you should use PDO instead of using mysql_query: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Can you describe more how it is failing currently? One thing that certainly looks like a problem is that you are using `$sqlStremail` in your INSERT statement instead of `$variable`.

Answer (score 1):

You better Use MySQLi class library. Something like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("",$mysqlUser,$mysqlPass,$mysqlTable);
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
         print FALSE; exit();
            }

$query = "SELECT UserID FROM User WHERE Name = '$dkuser'";
$result=$mysqli->query($query);
if($mysqli->query($query)==False) {print mysqli_error($mysqli); exit();}
if($result->num_rows>0)
        {  $row = $result->fetch_array();

       echo $row["UserID"];  

        } else

          { echo "User not found"; }
```